# Write DAX measures to Push Datasets using Power BI REST API

Tags: rest, powerbi, dataset, dax

I have successfully created push datasets in Power BI using the following method and endpoint:

```
response: requests.Response = pbi_client.post(
    f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{TEST_GROUP_ID}/datasets",
    json={
        "name": "Programmatically Created Dataset",
        "defaultMode": "Push",
        "tables": 
        [
            {
                "name": "raw",
                "columns": [
                    
                ]
            }
        ],
    }
)
```

Now, I am able to write rows to this dataset quite easily. However, the reports being bound to it require me to have some DAX measures in place that dictate the contents of some calculated columns.

The REST API [references measures in the context of Push Datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/push-datasets/datasets-get-tables-in-group#measure), but I cannot find a reference to the "measures" attribute of these datasets (and therefore change them, or create new ones).

*How would one write a measure to a dataset (or table within a dataset) using the Power BI REST API?*

I am aware of the [executeQueries endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/execute-queries-in-group), but this would return the result of the queries, and I would then need to reformat this response and write the resultant tables back to the dataset.